# How to define type of ref parameter when using React.forwardRef()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, ref, react-forwardref

My typescript compiler is throwing an error when using the forwardRef function. How should I be defining the type for ref?

Form.tsx

```
//react hook form 
    const {
        handleSubmit, 
        register, 
        watch, 
        formState: { errors }, 
    } = useForm( { defaultValues: state, mode: "onSubmit" }); 

// Input Component
<Input 
    {...register("firstName", { required: "First name is required"})}
     id="first-name"
  />
```

Input.tsx

```
export const Input = forwardRef((props, ref:RefType) => {
  return <input ref={ref} className="form-control" {...props} />;
});           //typescript error 

// what should RefType be?
```

As a workaround I assigned `ref: any` to get rid of the compiler error.

Comment: `HTMLInputElement`?

Comment: What types of refs will be accepted? An example:
`import {Ref} from 'react'`
`ref: Ref<YourInputRefType>`

Comment: @hoangtd I think I am lacking undestanding of the ref object. But could the type of ref be inferred from the props given the <Input/> component in Form.tsx?

Comment: @WmelonMan Yes it's inferred from within Form.tsx. And in Input.tsx you will define the types that the ref can receive. Like this:
`type FormInputRef = {
  updateInput: () => void
}`
`ref?: Ref<FromInputRef>`

Comment: @hoangtd thanks! I made the following defs:
 `type FormInputRef = {
  id: string;
  type?: string;
};

type Ref = HTMLInputElement;`

with: `export const Input = forwardRef<Ref, FormInputRef>((props, ref)`